# Create date from number of days

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to convert the number of days since `Jan 01 1970` to `JavaScript Date`.

Here is the code snippet.

```
new Date(864e5 * parseInt(data[i].d));
//here data[i].d contains number of days.
```

I checked all the data by this.

```
console.log(typeof(data[i].d), data[i].d);
//prints
number 17674
```

but sometimes it unable to convert it into date.

```
Invalid Date {}
```

while for

```
number 17858
//outputs.
Fri Aug 17 2018 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There are two reasons this might happen: `864e5 * parseInt(data[i].d)` returns NaN, or the result is larger than the maximum value allowed as input to the Date constructor. The largest number of days supported is ±100,000,000 (±1e8), so if `data[i].d` is larger than that, you'll get an invalid date. Without knowing the actual values of *data[i].d*, it's impossible to say which factor is causing the issue (note that `typeof NaN == 'number'`). Your first step should be to find the maximum and minimum values of the data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add the number of days times the milliseconds in a day, like so:

```
  var originalDay = new Date(864e5)
  console.log(originalDay) //Thu Jan 01 1970 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

  var numOfDays = 7
  var daysSince = new Date(864e5 + parseInt(numOfDays * 864e5))
  console.log(daysSince) //Thu Jan 08 1970 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) --7 days later
```

To make this work for you, you would just have to replace that `numOfDays` with the values in your array.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. *parseInt* is redundant in `parseInt(numOfDays * 864e5)` since the multiplication always returns a number, and for the OP *data[i].d* is a number. `new Date(864e5 + numOfDays * 864e5)` is what the OP is already doing, except you're adding an extra day. Why? How does this avoid the *Invalid Date* issue the OP mentioned? And why does it occur?